# How can an airplane roll, yaw and pitch up and down without control surfaces?

Tags: flight-controls, control-surfaces

This is a Sprat 103 ultralight, it has no ailerons, and no ruddervator (on its v-tail). How then does it fly controllably?

[image: Sprat 103 Ultralight]

Comment: Early aircraft had no flight control surfaces either. They achieved control by flexing of the wing structure, much like birds do.

Answer (score 5):

The wing is split to two halves, each half is mounted on its own axis. By changing each half's angle of incidence (and thus angle of attack) changes the amount of lift generated by the relevant side.

See this [video](https://youtu.be/Z_sKsE_ZkRY?t=31s) of a scale model.

A scheme of the mechanism

[image]

Comment: That gives roll.  Moving the two halves together changes the incidence angle (aka decalage) between wing and stabilizer, giving pitch control -- and the vertical fin is sized to avoid excessive side slip and make the craft spirally stable, like a free flight model airplane.